# Padding and Text - Text being cut

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to bottom-align a div content with padding. However, for some reason padding keeps cutting the text.
You can see the working example here on cssdeck link
http://cssdeck.com/labs/wpj8sl4k

As you can see the bottom part of the text is cut, when the padding is removed everything gets back to normal.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effecting both divs by saying #content div. What you want is #content div#content1.

Comment: Right. But that's the problem. They're absolute positioned right on top of each other, so it cuts off one.

Comment: THank you very much! I did not notice this!

Comment: But then if you add content to `#content2` it will not appear in the red div

Comment: @ExplosionPills You would just have deal with each div separately.

Comment: @nick can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's hard to know exactly the intent behind the content here, but if it were me... I'd probably just wrap the two divs in a container, then stack to other two divs inside. Otherwise you could just say: #content {height:...}, #content1 {top:...}, #content2 {top:....}

Answer (score 2):

`#content2` *also* follows the same CSS rules, so it will appear above `#content`.  This is especially visible if you actually add content to it, and the effect is likely undesirable.  If you want `#content1` and `#content2` to flow together, you should wrap both of them in the absolutely positioned div and give them static positioning.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ctxinf3b

Comment: Thank you, I can see my mistake now!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from your body & it will work fine.

```
<div id="content2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use specific *padding* and *margin*

```
#content div{
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as MISHAK Said

Remove these lines. It does not make any sense.

```
<div id="content2">
</div>
```

Good luck!